# Comparing timestamp to actual time

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm creating a service in C# to control a plc via modbus. I have a table in mysql with several columns. 2 columns are timestamps, one is for start time and one is for finish time. The table is used to store certain information about a few appliances I'd like to control. If the current time is in between the value of start time and finish time i want to turn on that appliance. My problem is that I cant seem to think of a way of checking if the current real time is in between my specified start time and finish time from the table in my database. And i'll need to do this about 6 times as i'll have around 6 appliances. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your works that you have developed up to now.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE 
    StartTime > Now()
    AND
    EndTime < Now()`

If you do it in SQL in c# System.DateTime.Now()